# How to use Pojo to get the fields?

Tags: android, parsing, retrofit, pojo

Guys recently i switched to Retrofit from volley. 
there is a Pojo file which is converted from json.

```
public class JobModel {

    private int status;

    private List<JobsBean> jobs;

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<JobsBean> getJobs() {
        return jobs;
    }

    public void setJobs(List<JobsBean> jobs) {
        this.jobs = jobs;
    }

    public static class JobsBean {
        private String job_city;

        public String getJob_city() {
            return job_city;
        }
    }
}
```

but i don't know how to use this pojo file to extract the job_city from JobsBean class

As you can see there is an JsonArray jobs which is converted to

```
List<JobsBean>
```

having JsonObjects and the

```
JobsBean class
```

is containing all the job_city name.
How can i retrieve these job_city name in an array.
so that i can use them in my arrayadapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the POJO structure as follow:

```
public class JobModel {
    private int status;
    private List<JobsBean> jobs;

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<JobsBean> getJobs() {
        return jobs;
    }

    public void setJobs(List<JobsBean> jobs) {
        this.jobs = jobs;
    }
}

public class JobsBean {
    private String job_city;

    public String getJob_city() {
        return job_city;
    }

    public void setJob_city(String job_city) {
        this.job_city = job_city;
    }
}
```

The default GsonConverterFactory should be more than enough to handle this nested POJO. And you should be able to get the result like:

```
JobModel.getJobs().get(index).getJob_city();
```

Comment: @VishalJangid, Is it able to resolve your issue? You can accept the solution and help the other people who has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ArrayAdapter<JobsBean>` and it will take a `JobsBean` list as a parameter for the model data.

You will need to override `getView()` to read the data from the `JobsBean` item and put it into the list item view.